# YCM does not work with eclim

Tags: vim, eclim

I have eclim setup and working. I know this because

```
:PingEclim
```

shows

```
eclim   2.3.4
eclipse 4.3.2
Press ENTER or type command to continue
```

in appropriate colors and Ctrl-X, Ctrl-U show correct completions after a partial method name in insert mode.

However, YouCompleteMe does not work. To install YouCompleteMe, I added the following lines.

```
set rtp+=~/.vim/bundle/vundle/
call vundle#rc()
Bundle 'Valloric/YouCompleteMe'
let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'
```

When I type the partial method name, I expect to see the same completions as when I typed Ctrl-X Ctrl-u above. Instead what I see is

```
-- User defined completion (^U^N^P) Pattern not found
```

The "Pattern not found" part is in red color.

How do I verify YCM is installed correctly? What does the error message mean?

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

YCM triggers Eclim automatically. So you don't need to press `C-xC-u` to invoke completion.

And the configuration `let g:EclimCompletionMethod = 'omnifunc'` disabled the key combination and remap it to `C-xC-o`.

So, as long as you have installed YCM correctly and configured eclim correctly, you don't even bother to press control key to invoke eclim. And if you do want to complete manually, you can press C-xC-o.

The installation of YCM requires you to build a native C++ component. Please refer to the [official manual](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/). It has quick guide for both OSX and Linux. (and YCM isn't available on windows, sigh).

You don't need to verify the installation of YCM purposely. If YCM is in your runtimepath but not installed correctly, it will warn you at the startup of vim. If YCM works correctly, it will just popup when you are typing in insert mode.

Comment: I'd like to know if I have to configure a .ycm_extra_conf.py even with my eclim project configured correctly through the CProjectConfigs command, it's bogus to have to had that extra conf when my eclim auto-complete is already configured.

Comment: I thought it was the setup of ycm so I uninstalled and tried using the C-xC-o key combination for the options but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

OP probably forgot to create a `.project` file and to generate a project structure with `:ProjectCreate . -n java` (inside vim, when in the project root directory).

Answer (score 0):

YMC uses a built component, you need to compile that component, it's all in the [YMC github page](http://valloric.github.io/YouCompleteMe/)